# Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a simple SpringBoot application (version: 1.5.9.RELEASE) and using plain JPA. here is the **application.properties** file:

```
    server.port: 8083
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restdb
    spring.datasource.username=ricky
    spring.datasource.password=ricky
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

my **pom.xml** looks as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.chatrabazar</groupId>
        <artifactId>SpringBootRest</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>SpringBootRest</name>
        <description>Demo Project for Spring boot and Spring Rest</description>
        <parent>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
                    <relativePath />
        </parent>
        <properties>
                    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                                <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
                    <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                </plugin>
                    </plugins>
        </build>
```

When I try to run this application; **Run as Spring Boot App** it is resultiing into below exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.**UnsatisfiedDependencyException**: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method '**entityManagerFactory**' parameter 0; 
**nested exception is** org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '**entityManagerFactoryBuilder**' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; 
**nested exception is** org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '**jpaVendorAdapter**' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
**nested exception is** org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method '**jpaVendorAdapter**' threw exception; 
**nested exception is** java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/**OptimisticLockException**
```

Comment: Have you tried `mvn clean install`?

Comment: yes, I tried to do from command prompt as well. I executed as below.

Comment: **D:\Sapient_GTyagi_workspace\SpringBootRest>mvn clean install**

I am still getting the same set of exceptions in command line output.

Comment: can someone please suggest, where is the mistake in my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just tried with exactly your configuration and it works fine. Can you try deleting the folder in your maven repository `/org/hibernate` so as to download the dependencies again? Maybe something is corrupted there.